# How to send html data from node js to front end?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, express

I am currently creating an application where I used MongoDB to store login data , nodejs for creating API and front end JS HTML to display the page. I am Creating user where i pass the email id and password via fetch ajax POST call to the backend node server. The backend api route creating the user in DB. I want after creating the user I want to redirect to a different page. How can i do that? her is my code snippet.

//front end fetch call

```
async function  createUser(email , password) {

return fetch("http://localhost:3000/user", 
    { 

    // Adding method type

    method: "POST", 

    // Adding body or contents to send 

    headers :{
        "content-type": "application/json"
    },

    body: JSON.stringify({
        "userId" : email.value,
        "password" : password.value
    })
});

}
```

//beckend code

```
 app.post('/user', async (req, res) => {

// res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
// res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST,OPTIONS");
const {error} = validate(req.body);

if (error) {
return res.status(400).send(error.details[0].message);
}
let user = await User.findOne({userId : req.body.userId});
if(user) return res.status(400).send("User already registered");

let newUser = new User (
    {
        userId : req.body.userId,
        password : req.body.password
    }
);

newUser = await newUser.save();
res.redirect('/logged');
//res.send(newUser)
//res.send("<h1>Hi</h1>");
//res.sendFile((path.join(__dirname+'/loggedon.html')));
//res.send("<h1>Hi</h1>");
}

);

app.get('/logged' , function(req, res){
    res.send("<h1>Hi</h1>");
    // res.setHeader(200 , 'Content-Type' , 'text/html');
    // fs.readFile('./loggedon.html', function(err , data){
    //     res.write("<h1>Hi</h1>");
    // })

});
```

I was checking sending only HI. but this will work fine in local server. but how will i send data to Front end. Please let me know. comment lines are the things I already tried.

Answer (score 0):

`res.redirect` sends an HTTP redirect response which means "You asked for some data from this URL. You can get it from this URL instead".

Since you made the request with Ajax, the redirect will be followed, the new URL requested, and the result passed to the Ajax handler.

You haven't written a handler (or, if you have, you haven't bothered to include it in the question) so nothing happens.

---

Aside: It is important to note that it does not mean "Load the new URL in the main browser window".

The new URL will only be loaded in the main browser window if the request was intended to be loaded there in the first place.

Yours was not. It is an Ajax request.

---

You *could* have the Ajax handler assign a new value to `location` when the promise resolves.

Frankly, if you want to load a new page, I'd question the use of Ajax in the first place and just design the system to use a regular form submission with no client-side JS involved at all.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I am at the beginner level of this. I thought i will send an html file to the front-end and render it and will show it. However, in ajax i am getting a standard response when the promise is getting resolve. That is status code , redirect url and so on. So just want to know what i need to if i want to keep my front-end and and render it. I will push it in GitHub and send the link in sometime. Please help me here. :) Thanks :)

Comment: As per my understanding , just because ajax call only for single page application so i cannot load a new page using the ajax???